# MAximum Number of Modules

Tags: azure-iot-edge

[this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) states the maximum number of modules in a deployment is 20. I am having problems getting over 15. Nothing ever happens, no error messages but the modules don't get deployed.
I also would like to know if this is a soft limit and if it is, what is the process to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any error in edgeAgent log?  probably you hit the limit of twin message size; Maximum size per twin section (tags, desired properties, reported properties) is 8 KB.